# Adding an increment variable along with id name for a textbox not working in yii1 PHP framework

Tags: yii

I am creating a table in controller and passing it to view as AJAX response.Inside this table there is dropdown for each rows.When I select 'Other' option value I have to show a textbox near that dropdown in same column itself and save the value in each textbox.

Inorder to make each textbox id unique I am appending an Incrementalvariable $s1 along with 'othermerits-'.e.g. - id="othermerits-2".But when I inspect the element it shows only id="othermerits".I am giving my code sample below written in my controller.Please refer 'else' part.

```
if (isset($_POST['date'])) {
                $date = $_POST['date'];
                $academic = Academic::model()>findByAttributes(array('status' => 1));
            $students = Student::model()>findAllByAttributes(array('courseid' => $courseid, 'batchid' => $batchid)); 
            $sendtable = "";
            $sl = 1;

            foreach ($students as $student) {//! for each student studentid, 
student admission number and name is send to form
                $teacher = Teachercomments::model()>findByAttributes(array('studentid' => $student->studentid, 'courseid' => 
$courseid, 'batchid' => $batchid, 'date' => $date, 'academicid' => 
$academic->academicid, 'userid' => Yii::app()->user->userid, 'usertypeid' => 
Yii::app()->user->usertypeid));
                if (isset($teacher)) {
                      $sendtable = $sendtable . '<tr><td data-id="' . 
$student->studentid . '">' . $sl . '</td><td>' . $student->student_firstname 
. " " . $student->student_middlename . " " . $student->student_lastname . 
'</td><td>' . '<input type="text" name="merits" id="merits" value="' . 
$teacher->merit . '"  class="merits"></td><td><input type="text"  value="' . 
$teacher->demerit . '"  name="demerits" class="demerits"></td></tr>';
                 } else {
$sendtable = $sendtable . '<tr><td data-id="' . $students->studentid . '">' 
. $sl . '</td><td>' . $students->student_firstname . " " . $students->student_middlename . " " . $students->student_lastname . '</td><td><select 
name="merits" id="merits" class="merits" 
onchange="GetSelectedTextValue(this,'.$s1.')"><option value="Good 
Discipline">Good Discipline</option><option value="Good Listener">Good 
Listener</option><option value="Other">Other</option></select><input 
type="text" name="othermerits" id="othermerits-'.$s1.'" class="merits" 
style=""/></td><td><select name="demerits" class="demerits"><option 
value="Careless">Careless</option><option value="Bad Listener">Bad 
Listener</option><option value="Other">Other</option></select></td></tr>';
    }
 $sl = $sl + 1;
 }
            echo $sendtable;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's a typo but on this tow lines you use **$s1**

```
<select name="merits" id="merits" class="merits" onchange="GetSelectedTextValue(this,'.$s1.')">
<input type="text" name="othermerits" id="othermerits-'.$s1.'" class="merits" style=""/>
```

and your imcrement variable is **$sl**

```
$sl = $sl + 1;
```

Comment: Thank you so much.It worked.My variable was $sl.By mistake I entered $s1.